# Can't find distribution after installing TeXstudio and TeX Live

Tags: texlive, texstudio

I first installed TeXstudio, and then TeX Live-full,

but TeXstudio can't find any distribution.

OS: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

```
root@user1:latex -version
pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015/Debian)
kpathsea version 6.2.1
Copyright 2015 Peter Breitenlohner (eTeX)/Han The Thanh (pdfTeX).
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Peter Breitenlohner (eTeX)/Han The Thanh     (pdfTeX).
Compiled with libpng 1.6.17; using libpng 1.6.17
Compiled with zlib 1.2.8; using zlib 1.2.8
Compiled with poppler version 0.41.0

root@user1:tex -version
TeX 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2015/Debian)
kpathsea version 6.2.1
Copyright 2015 D.E. Knuth.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the TeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the TeX source.
Primary author of TeX: D.E. Knuth.
```

Should I manually set the "Command" config of TeXstudio?

Someone says that I should set PATH as:

```
PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/i386-linux:$PATH
```

But I found there's no `/local/texlive` in this folder.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't think the debian packaged version installs in /usr/local what does `which tex` report as the location of tex?

Comment: It returns: `/usr/bin/tex`, so what should I set my `PATH` as?

Comment: it is hard to imagine that `/usr/bin` is not already in your path

Comment: I think that is already on my PATH, but I really don't know why Texstudio can't find distribution.

Comment: It depends on your setup. How exactly do you start texstudio via a menu, or from the command line?

Comment: Also do you mind posting a screen shot of the commands pane in the texstudio configuration interface

Comment: I just posted my screenshots there. I tried to start TexStudio both on desktop and command line.

Comment: That looks very strange. Normally,  say, the pdflatex entry just says pdflatex plus some options.

Comment: I can confirm that TS 2.12 does this and 2.11 has has the Build pane filled in and is working fine (though my test was on 14.04, but that should not matter). I'm guessing they do something new here and that they does not test things correctly. I would suggest contacting the developers.

Comment: See my comment here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/349597/3929

Comment: I would install texstudio *after* texlive so TS could find TL.

Comment: Had the same issue in windows. [Answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/416027/137109) below solved it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to your screenshot, you installed TeX Live 2015, therefore I think the directory you add to the path variable, "`/usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/i386-linux`", makes no sense.

My solution (it worked for me) is following:

1. call `which latex` on your terminal
2. Copy the path of its output, e.g., `/usr/local/texlive/2017/bin/x86_64-linux/` (without the trailing 'latex'), in your **TexStudio Configuration** PATH.
   You should select `Options > Configure TexStudio > Build > Commands ($PATH)` As I show you in the picture below.
   (Notice that in order to see all options you must click on the box `Show Advanced Options` at the bottom left corner)
   [image]

Then just try to build your LaTeX file. Enjoy it!

Comment: I have fedora and this is not working for me

Comment: @SohamChatterjee what is not working? You only have two steps ;). The `which` command is a generic Linux command...

Comment: I followed the steps you said..but after adding the path in texstudio it is still showing no latex distribution

Comment: It might be a LaTeX installation problem. Try to execute the path given by `which latex`, that is, enter such path in terminal (for example, in my case is `/usr/bin/latex`). If latex is correctly executed it will output something like `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/Debian)`. If not, then the problem might be at LaTeX installation not at TeXStudio

Comment: I when i execute `which latex` it shows me `/usr/local/texlive/2021/bin/x86_64-linux/latex` nothing else and on executing `pdflatex` i get ```This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2021) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
**```

Comment: @SohamChatterjee there was an error in my explanation (thanks to DPiendl for correcting!) the last folder, i.e., `\latex`, must be deleted from the path. The answer to your problem arrived late, but it arrived (prayers were not in vain)